# Insert on duplicate key update returns value of 0

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I am creating a web page where you can edit local listing sites for clients. I am using the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax in mysql and php. Below is the code:

edit-listings-exec.php

```
<?
    //Array to store validation errors
    $errmsg_arr = array();

    //Validation error flag
    $errflag = false;

    $member_id = $_SESSION['MEMBER_ID'];
    $userresult = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT   username 
                                    FROM        members 
                                    WHERE       member_id = '$member_id'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($userresult);
    $username = $row['username'];


    //run a for loop to check for duplicates
    for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++) {
        $selectbox = $_POST['listing'.$i];

        for ($j=1; $j < 10; $j++) {
            if ($j != $i) {
                if ($_POST['listing'.$j] === $selectbox && $_POST['listing'.$j] != "") {
                $errmsg_arr[] = "Duplicate listing source '$selectbox'";
                $errflag = true;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //if there are input validations redirect back to main page
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: edit-listings.php");
        exit();
    }

    //run loop to define post variables
    for ($k=1; $k < 10; $k++) {
        ${'listing'.$k} = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['listing'.$k]);
        ${'listing'.$k.'_site'} = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['listing'.$k.'_site']);
    }


    //insert listings into local_listings table for the user
    $qry = "INSERT INTO local_listings (
                        member_id,
                        username,
                        listing1,
                        listing1_site,
                        listing2,
                        listing2_site,
                        listing3,
                        listing3_site,
                        listing4,
                        listing4_site,
                        listing5,
                        listing5_site,
                        listing6,
                        listing6_site,
                        listing7,
                        listing7_site,
                        listing8,
                        listing8_site,
                        listing9,
                        listing9_site)
                VALUES (
                        '$member_id',
                        '$username',
                        '$listing1',
                        '$listing1_site',
                        '$listing2',
                        '$listing2_site',
                        '$listing3',
                        '$listing3_site',
                        '$listing4',
                        '$listing4_site',
                        '$listing5',
                        '$listing5_site',
                        '$listing6',
                        '$listing6_site',
                        '$listing7',
                        '$listing7_site',
                        '$listing8',
                        '$listing8_site',
                        '$listing9',
                        '$listing9_site')
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                        listing1        =   '$listing1',
                        listing1_site   =   '$listing1_site',
                        listing2        =   '$listing2',
                        listing2_site   =   '$listing2_site',
                        listing3        =   '$listing3',
                        listing3_site   =   '$listing3_site',
                        listing4        =   '$listing4',
                        listing4_site   =   '$listing4_site',
                        listing5        =   '$listing5',
                        listing5_site   =   '$listing5_site',
                        listing6        =   '$listing6',
                        listing6_site   =   '$listing6_site',
                        listing7        =   '$listing7',
                        listing7_site   =   '$listing7_site',
                        listing8        =   '$listing8',
                        listing8_site   =   '$listing8_site',
                        listing9        =   '$listing9',
                        listing9_site   =   '$listing9_site'";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $qry);

    if (mysqli_affected_rows($result) < 1) {
        $errmsg_arr[] = "Unable to insert listings for $username";
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        header ("location: edit-listings.php");
    }
    elseif (mysqli_affected_rows($result) === 1) {
        $_SESSION['RESULT'] = "New listings for '$username' inserted successfully";
        header ("location: edit-listings-success.php");
    }
    elseif (mysqli_affected_rows($result) === 2) {
        $_SESSION['RESULT'] = "Listings for '$username' have been updated";
        header ("location: edit-listings-success.php");
    }


?>
```

The data is successfully inserting into the `local_listings` table but `mysqli_affected_rows` always returns a value of `0`. It should be returning a value of `1` if it inserts a new row or `2` if it simply updates. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please, use some meaningful names for the columns in the database table.

Comment: I have the columns named like that because they are each an `enum` field with many possible options and each one could be for a different site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    if (mysqli_affected_rows($link) < 1) {
... your code
}
```

take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: +1 The argument for the `mysqli_affected_rows` function should be the link (returned by mysqli_connect) rather than a resultset.